# Parallels shared folders not working

Tags: windows, sharing, parallels-desktop

I've followed the manual in setting up the shared folders on my Windows 7 installation under Parallels version 7.0.15106, but still I can not find my Mac folders in Windows explorer! I have tried both the "Shared Profile" and adding shared folders manually. As I understand it, they should show up under Network in Windows Explorer, right? Well, the only thing showing up there is MyName-WIN7 which contains a Users folder, which in turn contains a folder with my name and a folder called Public. The contents of the folder with my name is the same as in C:\Users\MyName and has nothing to do with anything on the Mac. I have Googled until my eyes turned red for a solution, but everyone just says the same thing - Go to Configure > Sharing, etc. Well I have tried all of that, there must be some setting that's prohibiting my shared Mac folders from showing up in Windows... I have made sure that the "Isolate my Mac" setting is turned off, so that's not it either.

Answer (score 1):

On my Parallels 8 installation, they're mounted as `\\psf\` which is also mapped to drive `Z:`.

Comment: Correct. In Windows Explorer, look under Computer, not Network. I'm on Parallels 9 and my Mac's home folder is also mapped to drive Z.